# Identifier 'Submission#0' is not CLS-compliant in Azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I hope somebody could help me on this one. I am implementing an Azure Function where I am trying to serialise an XML message into .Net object. This is the code that I am currently using:

```
public static void Run(string input, TraceWriter log) 
{
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(App));
    // more code here....
}
public class App
{
    public string DataB { get; set; }
}
```

However, I always got this error:

```
2017-01-17T12:21:35.173 Exception while executing function: Functions.ManualXmlToJson. mscorlib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. System.Xml: Identifier 'Submission#0' is not CLS-compliant.
```

Parameter name: ident.

I have tried with XmlAttributes, without them. I added the `buildOptions:warningsAsErrors` as `false` in `project.json` file but nothing happens. And to be honest, I ran out of ideas because this code is actually working in an App Console.

I guess is some parameter of something, I would really appreciate if somebody can suggest me how to fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: carlosm, curious to know if the answer below helped. Please let us know if you're still having issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best option here will be to factor the class you're attempting to serialize into a separate class library and reference that from your function.

If you implement your `App` class above in a different assembly, your function code would look like the following:

```
#r "<yourassemblyname>.dll"

using System;
using <YourClassNamespace>;

public static void Run(string input, TraceWriter log) 
{
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(App));
}
```

The code above assumes a private assembly reference, where you upload your assembly to a bin folder, inside of your function folder.

You can find more about external references here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#referencing-external-assemblies

I'm opening an issue to address the CLS compliant name so this is not as confusing:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/1123

Another option worth trying (which would minimize the changes you'd need to make to your code) is to use the DataContractSerializer instead. You can find more information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Here is a quick sample of a function using the `DataContractSerializer` (with your type above):

```
#r "System.Runtime.Serialization"

using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

public static void Run(string input, TraceWriter log) 
{
   string xml = WriteObject(new App { DataB = "Test"});
   log.Info(xml);
}


[DataContract(Name = "App")]
public class App
{
    [DataMember]
    public string DataB { get; set; }
}




public static string WriteObject(App app)
{
    using (var output = new StringWriter())
    using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(output) { Formatting = Formatting.Indented })
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(App));
        serializer.WriteObject(writer, app);

        return output.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```