# C# script Identifier 'Submission#0' is not CLS-compliant

Tags: c#

I have to create c# script on teamcity pipelines,
i have tested it locally running from code (instead of dotnet-script) and it worked, but whenever i try use dotnet-script it returns me an error

> System.ArgumentException: Identifier 'Submission#0' is not
> CLS-compliant. (Parameter 'ident')    at
> System.Xml.Serialization.CodeIdentifier.CheckValidIdentifier(String
> ident)    at
> System.Xml.Serialization.CodeIdentifier.EscapeKeywords(String
> identifier, StringBuilder sb)    at
> System.Xml.Serialization.CodeIdentifier.GetCSharpName(Type t, Type[]
> parameters, Int32 index, StringBuilder sb)    at
> System.Xml.Serialization.CodeIdentifier.GetCSharpName(Type t, Type[]
> parameters, Int32 index, StringBuilder sb)    at
> System.Xml.Serialization.CodeIdentifier.GetCSharpName(Type t)    at
> System.Xml.Serialization.TypeDesc.get_CSharpName()    at
> System.Xml.Serialization.SourceInfo.CastTo(TypeDesc td)

[image]
my whole code is one single file (verifier2.csx):

This is the source:

```
#r "System.Runtime.Serialization"

using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Linq;


VerifyAndGetNotIncludedInXml();


[XmlRoot(ElementName = "File")]
public class FileNewFile
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "KeyPath")]
    public string KeyPath { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Source")]
    public string Source { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Component")]
public class ComponentNewFile
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "File")]
    public FileNewFile File { get; set; } 
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Guid")]
    public string Guid { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "NeverOverwrite")]
    public string NeverOverwrite { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ComponentGroup")]
public class ComponentGroup
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Component")]
    public List<ComponentNewFile> Component { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Directory")]
    public string Directory { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Fragment")]
public class Fragment
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ComponentGroup")]
    public List<ComponentGroup> ComponentGroup { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CustomAction")]
    public object CustomAction { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "InstallExecuteSequence")]
    public object InstallExecuteSequence { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Wix", Namespace = "http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs")]
public class WixNewFile
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Fragment")]
    public Fragment Fragment { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xmlns")]
    public string Xmlns { get; set; }
}

 public string[] VerifyAndGetNotIncludedInXml(string filePath = _teamCityfilePath, string buildPath = _teamCitybuildPath)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("verifying");
        var excluded = new[] { "appsettings.json" };
        var files = new List<string>();
        foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(buildPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            if(!excluded.Any(x=> newPath.Contains(x)))
                files.Add(newPath);
        }

        var wixModel = GetFilesModel(filePath);
        
        var wixFilesModel = wixModel.Fragment;
        var wixfileNames = wixFilesModel.ComponentGroup.SelectMany(x => x.Component.Select(y => y.File.Source)).ToArray();

        var filesPath = WithoutPath(files);
        var wixInstallerFilesPath = WithoutPath(wixfileNames);


        var filesInXmlNotExistingInBuild = wixInstallerFilesPath.Where(x => !filesPath.Contains(x));
        if (filesInXmlNotExistingInBuild.Any())
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("Files for installer not exists in build catalog:");
            foreach (var file in filesInXmlNotExistingInBuild)
                sb.AppendLine(file);

            throw new Exception(sb.ToString());
        }

        var filesNotIncludedInXML = filesPath.Where(x => !wixInstallerFilesPath.Contains(x)).ToArray();
        var dllsNotIncludedInXml = filesNotIncludedInXML.Where(x => x.Contains(".dll")).ToArray();

        FixNotIncludedFilesInXML(dllsNotIncludedInXml, wixModel);
        return dllsNotIncludedInXml;
    }

    public void FixNotIncludedFilesInXML(string[] files, WixNewFile serialized) 
    {
        string setupCatalog = @"Setup";
        var allowedChars = GetAllowedChars();
        

        foreach(var file in files)
        {
            ComponentGroup componentGroup = null;

            if (FileIsInDirectory(file))
            {
                var directoryId = GetDirectoryId(file);
                componentGroup = serialized.Fragment.ComponentGroup.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == directoryId);
                if(componentGroup == null)
                {
                    var path = GetDirectoryPath(file);
                    if (_platformsDictionary.ContainsKey(path))
                    {
                        directoryId = _platformsDictionary[path];
                        componentGroup = serialized.Fragment.ComponentGroup.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == directoryId);
                        if(componentGroup == null)
                        {
                            serialized.Fragment.ComponentGroup.Add(new ComponentGroup
                            {
                                Id = directoryId,
                                Directory = directoryId,
                                Component = new List<ComponentNewFile>()
                            });
                            componentGroup = serialized.Fragment.ComponentGroup.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == directoryId);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                componentGroup = serialized.Fragment.ComponentGroup.First(x => x.Id == "ProductComponents");
            }
            componentGroup?.Component.Add(new ComponentNewFile
            {
                Id = GetNewId("cmp", allowedChars),
                Guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                File = new FileNewFile
                {
                    KeyPath = "yes",
                    Source = setupCatalog+file,
                    Id = GetNewId("fil", allowedChars)
                }
            });
        }

        SerializeAndSave(serialized);
    }

    private string GetDirectoryId(string file)
    {
        var directories = string.Empty;
        var paths = file.Split('\\');
        var result = paths[paths.Length - 2];
        return WithoutSpecialChars(result);
    }

    private string GetDirectoryPath(string file)
    {
        var directories = string.Empty;
        var paths = file.Split('\\');
        for(int i=1;i<paths.Length-1; i++)
        {
            directories += $@"{paths[i]}\";
        }

        return directories;
    }

    private string WithoutSpecialChars(string path)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        foreach(var c in path)
        {
            if (char.IsLetter(c) || char.IsNumber(c))
                result += c;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private bool FileIsInDirectory(string file)
        => file.Count(c => c == '\\') > 1;


    Dictionary<string, string> _platformsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {@"runtimes\unix\lib\netcoreapp3.1\","unixlibnetcoreapp3" },
        {@"runtimes\unix\lib\net6.0\", "unixlibnet6" },
        {@"runtimes\win\lib\netcoreapp3.1\","winlibnetcoreapp3" },
        {@"runtimes\win\lib\netstandard2.0\","winlibnetstandard2" },
        {@"runtimes\win-x64\native\","winx64native" },
        {@"runtimes\win-x86\native\","winx86native" },
        {@"runtimes\win\lib\net6.0\", "winarmlibnet6" },
        {@"runtimes\win-arm\native\","winarmnative" },
        {@"runtimes\win-arm64\native\","winarm64native" }
    };

    public void SerializeAndSave(WixNewFile value)
    {
        var emptyNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty });
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(WixNewFile));
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

        using (var stream = new StringWriter())
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value, emptyNamespaces);

            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\temp\directory.wxs", stream.ToString());
        }
    }

    char[] GetAllowedChars()
    {
        var allowedChars = new List<char>();

        for (var i = 65; i <= 90; i++) //capital letters
            allowedChars.Add((char)i);

        for(var i=48;i<=57;i++) //numbers
            allowedChars.Add((char)i);

        return allowedChars.ToArray();
    }
    string GetNewId(string prefix, char[] allowedChars)
    {

        string result = prefix;
        int charsCount = 32;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < charsCount; i++)
        {
            var random = new System.Random().Next(0, allowedChars.Count() - 1);
            result += allowedChars[random];
        }
        return result;
    }

    public string[] WithoutPath(IEnumerable<string> files)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();

        foreach(var file in files)
        {
            var path = file.Substring(file.IndexOf("Setup") + "Setup".Length);
            result.Add(path);
        }
        return result.ToArray();
    }

    public WixNewFile GetFilesModel(string filePath)
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(WixNewFile));
        WixNewFile wixObject;
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(filePath))
        {
            wixObject = (WixNewFile)ser.Deserialize(reader);
        }

        return wixObject;
    }
    
    
    const string _teamCityfilePath = @"Installer\Directory.wxs";
    const string _teamCitybuildPath = @"bin\Release\net6.0";
```

it fails in this method:

```
  public WixNewFile GetFilesModel(string filePath)
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(WixNewFile));
        WixNewFile wixObject;
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(filePath))
        {
            wixObject = (WixNewFile)ser.Deserialize(reader);
        }

        return wixObject;
    }
```

tried to google problem and add this to the classess

> [assembly:CLSCompliant(true)]

but then i get error:

> PS C:\Users\pawel\OneDrive\Pulpit> dotnet-script .\verifier2.csx
> C:\Users\pawel\OneDrive\Pulpit.\verifier2.csx(60,2): error CS1730:
> Assembly and module attributes must precede all other elements defined
> in a file except using clauses and extern alias declarations

whole stack:

> System.ArgumentException: Identifier 'Submission#0' is not
> CLS-compliant. (Parameter 'ident')    at
> System.Xml.Serialization.CodeIdentifier.CheckValidIdentifier(String
> ident)    at
> System.Xml.Serialization.CodeIdentifier.EscapeKeywords(String
> identifier, StringBuilder sb)    at
> System.Xml.Serialization.CodeIdentifier.GetCSharpName(Type t, Type[]
> parameters, Int32 index, StringBuilder sb)    at
> System.Xml.Serialization.CodeIdentifier.GetCSharpName(Type t, Type[]
> parameters, Int32 index, StringBuilder sb)    at
> System.Xml.Serialization.CodeIdentifier.GetCSharpName(Type t)    at
> System.Xml.Serialization.TypeDesc.get_CSharpName()    at
> System.Xml.Serialization.SourceInfo.CastTo(TypeDesc td)    at
> System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterILGen.WriteElements(SourceInfo
> source, String enumSource, ElementAccessor[] elements, TextAccessor
> text, ChoiceIdentifierAccessor choice, String arrayName, Boolean
> writeAccessors, Boolean isNullable)    at
> System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterILGen.WriteMember(SourceInfo
> source, String choiceSource, ElementAccessor[] elements, TextAccessor
> text, ChoiceIdentifierAccessor choice, TypeDesc memberTypeDesc,
> Boolean writeAccessors)    at
> System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterILGen.GenerateTypeElement(XmlTypeMapping
> xmlTypeMapping)    at
> System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterILGen.GenerateElement(XmlMapping
> xmlMapping)    at
> System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateRefEmitAssembly(XmlMapping[]
> xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace)    at
> System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings,
> Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, String location)    at
> System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateTempAssembly(XmlMapping
> xmlMapping, Type type, String defaultNamespace, String location)    at
> System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, String
> defaultNamespace)    at
> System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type)    at
> Submission#0.GetFilesModel(String filePath) in
> C:\Users\pawel\OneDrive\Pulpit\verifier2.csx:line 266    at
> Submission#0.VerifyAndGetNotIncludedInXml(String filePath, String
> buildPath) in C:\Users\pawel\OneDrive\Pulpit\verifier2.csx:line 79
> at Submission#0.<>d__0.MoveNext() in
> C:\Users\pawel\OneDrive\Pulpit\verifier2.csx:line 8
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---    at Dotnet.Script.Core.ScriptRunner.Execute[TReturn](String dllPath,
> IEnumerable`1 commandLineArgs) in
> C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpFE4C\Dotnet.Script.Core\ScriptRunner.cs:line
> 110

Comment: It's weird that compiler complains about "Submission#0", yet there is no word "submission" in your code. Something's amiss here.

Comment: looks related https://stackoverflow.com/q/41697453/73226

Comment: yeah, looked at this topic too and tried and still same

Comment: 'Submission#0' is just my code, the problem is at line 
   XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(WixNewFile));

Comment: A # is invalid in a C# identifier, no attribute will help there

Comment: what are you talking about, Hans ?

Comment: actually this is same situation : https://github.com/dotnet/interactive/issues/1881 and still dunno how to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

It is not solution to problem with script, but i've researched and didn't find any solutions - as mentioned in comments, there was reported same problem there github.com/dotnet/interactive/issues/1881

In the end - instead of using C# script on teamcity pipeline, i have created .net6 console app (with this code) and using "dotnet run [project]" on teamcity - and it works as expected.